# Attribute accessor not satisfying role requirement when using Moops and Moose

Tags: perl, moose, moops

Consider the following code sample:

```perl
use Moops;

role RoleA
using Moose {
  requires 'm1';
  method m2() {
    $self->m1." World!\n";
  }
}

role RoleB
using Moose {
  has 'm1' => ( accessor => 'm1', is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', default => 'Hello');
}

class ClassA
with RoleB
with RoleA
using Moose {
  method m3() {
    $self->m2();
  }
}

print ClassA->new()->m3();
```

"Compilation" fails, because the attribute accessor does not seem to satisfy the roles request for `m1`:

```
$ perl roletest.pl 
'RoleB|RoleA' requires the method 'm1' to be implemented by 'ClassA' at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Moose/Meta/Role/Application/ToClass.pm line 134.
    Moose::Meta::Role::Application::ToClass::check_required_methods('Moose::Meta::Role::Application::ToClass=HASH(0x28b9d00)', 'Moose::Meta::Role::Composite=HASH(0x28c6270)', 'Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x28ee7c0)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Moose/Meta/Role/Application.pm line 55
    Moose::Meta::Role::Application::apply('Moose::Meta::Role::Application::ToClass=HASH(0x28b9d00)', 'Moose::Meta::Role::Composite=HASH(0x28c6270)', 'Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x28ee7c0)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Moose/Meta/Role/Application/ToClass.pm line 36
    Moose::Meta::Role::Application::ToClass::apply('Moose::Meta::Role::Application::ToClass=HASH(0x28b9d00)', 'Moose::Meta::Role::Composite=HASH(0x28c6270)', 'Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x28ee7c0)', 'HASH(0x28e3410)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Moose/Meta/Role.pm line 470
    Moose::Meta::Role::apply('Moose::Meta::Role::Composite=HASH(0x28c6270)', 'Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x28ee7c0)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Moose/Util.pm line 163
    Moose::Util::_apply_all_roles('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x28ee7c0)', undef, 'RoleB', 'RoleA') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Moose/Util.pm line 99
    Moose::Util::apply_all_roles('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x28ee7c0)', 'RoleB', 'RoleA') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Moose.pm line 66
    Moose::with('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x28ee7c0)', 'RoleB', 'RoleA') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Moose/Exporter.pm line 409
    Moose::with('RoleB', 'RoleA') called at roletest.pl line 16
    main::BEGIN() called at roletest.pl line 23
    eval {...} called at roletest.pl line 23
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at roletest.pl line 23.
```

Using plain `Moose` and `Moose::Role` this [works](https://gist.github.com/sschober/8785012) (as is documented [here](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Moose-2.1202/lib/Moose/Manual/Roles.pod#Required_Attributes)). Also, not using the `Moose` backend [works to](https://gist.github.com/sschober/8784886).

I already tried switching the order of the `with` statements to no avail. Replacing the attribute with a method declaration solves the problem, but I need a way to specify attribute requirements.

Is there a way to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it works with plain Moose? Because I've tried this and it fails with a very similar error message:

```
use v5.14;
use strict;
use warnings;

package RoleA {
    use Moose::Role;
    requires 'm1';
    sub m2 {
        my $self = shift;
        $self->m1." World!\n";
    }
}

package RoleB {
    use Moose::Role;
    has 'm1' => ( accessor => 'm1', is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', default => 'Hello');
}

package ClassA {
    use Moose;
    with qw/ RoleB RoleA /;
    sub m3 {
        my $self = shift;
        $self->m2();
    }
}

print ClassA->new()->m3();
```

There are a number of issues in Moose (and corresponding TODO test cases in the test suite) revolving around attributes in roles not satisfying `requires` in other roles. For example, bug [RT#77406](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=77406) is similar (though not identical).

**UPDATE** by manually composing the roles one-at-a-time, in a particular order, you can make it work:

```
use Moops;

role RoleA using Moose {
  requires 'm1';
  method m2() {
    $self->m1." World!\n";
  }
}

role RoleB using Moose {
  has 'm1' => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', default => 'Hello' );
}

class ClassA using Moose {
  with 'RoleB';
  with 'RoleA';
  method m3() {
    $self->m2();
  }
}

print ClassA->new()->m3();
```

Comment: I've updated my question referencing my working examples: [Moo-Version](https://gist.github.com/sschober/8784886), [Moose-Version](https://gist.github.com/sschober/8785012). The only difference I can see is you specify packages using braces.

Comment: Aha! You're composing the roles individually - `with 'RoleB'; with 'RoleA';`. I am composing them together - `with 'RoleB', 'RoleA';`. That's an important difference. Moops always composes them together. However, see Update.